# Django-cms placeholder translation, rendering with respect to language

Tags: django-cms

I would like to know how to manually translate a placeholder in Django-cms.

If I use the tag `{% placeholder "test" %}`, I can only define the value of test once for all languages. Is it possible to define the same placeholder multiple times for all languages used on the website? Or should I create different placeholders `test_en`, `test_fr`, `test_es` and use an `if` clause within my template? It is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given any details on how you build your pages but I'm guessing you have created your own with your custom setup of placeholders. Any regular django-cms pages are translatable by default if you configure multiple languages in your settings.

Note that it is preferable to translate the container that holds the placeholder(s) than each placeholder separately.

If you define your own pages you can make those translation aware using `django-hvad` (which is also what `django-cms` uses):

```
# models.py

from cms.models import PlaceholderField, Placeholder
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from hvad.manager import TranslationAwareManager

class LanguageManager(TranslationAwareManager):
    def for_language(self, language):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(Q(language__isnull=True) | Q(language=language))


class CustomPage(models.Model):

    language = models.CharField(_('language'), max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
                                help_text=_('leave empty to display in all languages'))

    placeholder_abstract = PlaceholderField('abstract', related_name='%(class)s_abstracts')
    placeholder_content = PlaceholderField('content', related_name='%(class)s_contents')
    placeholder_links = PlaceholderField('links', related_name='%(class)s_links')

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, related_name='+', editable=False)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, related_name='+', editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    objects = LanguageManager()
```

[Django Hvad](http://django-hvad.readthedocs.io) has many more goodies for translating models.